# Allowing duplicate rows in Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose model that looks like this:

```
var appSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },

  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date  
});
```

I want to be able to insert multiple entries into this collection with duplicate `name`. When I try doing that right now, it says that there are duplicate keys. how can I insert multiple rows with the same attributes but with different `_id`.

Comment: Can you add your require/init code and also the document saving statements?

Comment: try: `name: { type: String, unique: false }`